# ios 8 UITextField hides under Predictive View in iOS 8

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitextfield, ios8

I am developing a chat application in which I have `UIView` with `UITableView` and at the bottom of the `UIView` there is another `UIView`(say userInputView) with a `UITextField` and a `UIButton` added as a subview on it.

When the user taps on the `UITextField` keyboard appears and this `UIView`(userInputView) moves up to adjust itself as per keyboard height using `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`.

When I tap the "Send" Button, I set the text of `UITextField` to nil.

This is working fine till iOS 7 but in iOS 8 when I change the text of the `UITextField` the userInputView view is hiding under predictive text view. When I minimize the predictive text view then userInputView is displayed again but when I maximize predictive textview it hides again.

All of this is happening when I try to change to change the text of `UITextField` on tapping the send button. If I don't change the text of `UITextField` then it works fine.

How can I resolve this issue in iOS8? Even if I hide predictive text view the userInputView will hide and never display again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as yours but after checking the keyboard notifications enums.So,I used UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification or UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification because these will tell you the change in keyboard frame when **predictive text bar gets up or down when keyboard is in view** or **user turn on or turn off from setting**. Below is the code which working perfectly.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];



-(void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

if (kKeyBoardFrame.size.height == HEIGHT_OF_KEYBOARD) {
    [viewCommentText setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kKeyBoardFrame.size.height+32, 320, viewCommentText.frame.size.height)];
}else if (kKeyBoardFrame.size.height == 224){
    [viewCommentText setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kKeyBoardFrame.size.height+18, 320, viewCommentText.frame.size.height)];
}else{
    [viewCommentText setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kKeyBoardFrame.size.height-viewCommentText.frame.size.height, 320, viewCommentText.frame.size.height)];
}
}
```

and also remove observer when you are leaving your view

```
#pragma mark Device constrols Constant
#define HEIGHT_OF_STATUS_BAR 20
#define HEIGHT_OF_TOOLBAR 44
#define HEIGHT_OF_TABLE_CELL 44
#define HEIGHT_OF_TAB_BAR 49
#define HEIGHT_OF_SEARCH_BAR 44
#define HEIGHT_OF_NAVIGATION_BAR 44
#define HEIGHT_OF_TEXTFIELD 31
#define HEIGHT_OF_PICKER 216
#define HEIGHT_OF_KEYBOARD 216
#define HEIGHT_OF_SEGMENTED_CONTROL 43
#define HEIGHT_OF_SEGMENTED_CONTROL_BAR 29
#define HEIGHT_OF_SEGMENTED_CONTROL_BEZELED 40
#define HEIGHT_OF_SWITCH 27
#define HEIGHT_OF_SLIDER 22
#define HEIGHT_OF_PROGRESS_BAR 9
#define HEIGHT_OF_PAGE_CONTROL 36
#define HEIGHT_OF_BUTTON 37
```